# How to get User json data with google Oauth2

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm attempting to send back my token to request further information about the user logging in. I want to get json back.

using the code below I get an exception "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

What am I doing wrong?

```
 public void Login(Action<Mobile.Google.Account> googleLoginCompleted, Action googleLoginFailed)
    {

        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
              clientId: "myid",
              clientSecret: "secret",
              scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
              authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"),
              redirectUrl: new Uri("http://adults.wicareerpathways.org"),
               accessTokenUrl: new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"));

    auth.Completed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.IsAuthenticated)
            {

                var values = e.Account.Properties;
                var access_token = values["access_token"];

                var googleAccount = new Mobile.Google.Account
                {
                    Username = e.Account.Username,
                    Properties = e.Account.Properties
                };

                try
                {

                    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format(@"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?access_token=" + access_token + "&format=json", ""));
                    request.ContentType = "application/json";
                    request.Method = "GET";
                    var user_ID = values["user_id"];

                    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                    {
                        System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Stautus Code is: {0}", response.StatusCode);

                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            var content = reader.ReadToEnd();

                            GoogleAccountDetails result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleAccountDetails>(content);

                            googleAccount.Username = result.id;

                            if (googleLoginCompleted != null)
                            {
                                googleLoginCompleted(googleAccount);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception exx)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(exx.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than directly solving your problem, let me give you some advice on how to solve this yourself.

It seems obvious that a key isn't present. The first important thing is to figure out which line exactly the problem is. I see two possibilities, "user_id" and "access_token". One of those two items must not be included. Both come from values. Try printing out values, and see what you come up with. In particular, print the keys, and see if you have a typo.

Looking at your code, I suspect your error is in the second, `var user_ID = values["user_id"];` First of all, you don't seem to use it anywhere. Secondly, it is different than the `clientId` used earlier. In fact, I would suggest just using `clientId`, if that is what you intend, which will give you consistency in your requesting values.

Comment: Thanks that helped. New to this and didn't understand the error. The error was on the user id like like you thought.